# datagridview checkbox column as radiobutton for single selected row

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have about 1000 rows in a `DataGridView`. 
Want to implement a `CheckBox` column for users to select single row.
Current implementation is slow during the initial select. The loop is causing the problem:

```
dataGridView_1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   dataGridView_1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);


private void dataGridView_1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView_1.Columns["Selected"].Index)
    if (Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView_1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value) == 1)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow DR in dataGridView_PrimeMover.Rows)
        {
            if (DR.Index != e.RowIndex)
            {
               DR.Cells[0].Value = 0;
            }
        }
    ......
    ......
   }
}
```

How to implement a lookalike `RadioButton` column in the `DataGridView` which can handle large data?

Comment: Why don't you disable the multiselect of the datagridview? So you can get the selected row directly.

Comment: but i want to select only 1 single checkbox

Comment: Oh then you have to add a checkbox template field in the grid and add the checked state changed event and in the event, you loop through all the checkbox column of the grid, if more than one checkbox checked, uncheck the checkbox

Comment: but how to handle large data loop. 
my initial select of a checkbox is very slow.
something wrong with my looping

Comment: Sorry, just now went to lunch, please take a look at my answer, see if it helps

Comment: You said you want the column acting like a RadioButton, but you aren't toggling anywhere. Unless `dataGridView_1` and `dataGridView_PrimeMover` were suppose to be the same dgv? Can you clarify, how many dgv's do you have? And should they both have a CheckBoxColumn that acts as a RadioButton and are always synced together?

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

I've changed the if case inside the foreach loop, you don't need to assign value to every row, see if it's faster

```
if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView_1.Columns["Selected"].Index)
    if (Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView_1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value) == 1)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow DR in dataGridView_PrimeMover.Rows)
        {
            if((int)DR.Columns["Selected"] == 1 && DR.Index != e.RowIndex)
                DR.Columns["Selected"] = 0;
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

So many DataGridView's events know me but I don't know them, hope this help.

```
    int SelectedRowIndex;

    private void InitDGVData()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc = new DataColumn();
        DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn();
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(i.ToString(), i.ToString());
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        col.Name = "Selected";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
        SelectedRowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
        dataGridView1.Rows[SelectedRowIndex].Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Selected"].Index].Value = true;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["Selected"].Index && e.RowIndex != SelectedRowIndex)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[SelectedRowIndex].Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Selected"].Index].Value = false;
            SelectedRowIndex = e.RowIndex;
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[SelectedRowIndex].Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Selected"].Index].Value = true;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["Selected"].Index && e.RowIndex == SelectedRowIndex)
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```